# Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: android

I'm gettin always this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
 Process: com.langa.a1956, PID: 24253
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
 com.langa.a1956.Archivum.UI.SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity$1$1.startActivityJSON(SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity.java:49)
```

This is my code:

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            page = 1;
            while (page <= 27) {
                jsonData = new JSON("http://1956.osaarchivum.org/api/items?collection=13&page=" + page + "&per_page=50", SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity.this);
                Log.v("Current page:", page + "");
                jsonData.mJSONInterface = new JSONInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void startActivityJSON() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.getCollections().length; i++) {
                            Log.v("Current I:", i + "");
                            final JSONMedia jsonMedia = new JSONMedia(jsonData.getCollections()[i].getMediaURL(), SzabadEuMusorokLeirasActivity.this);
                            final int finalI = i;
                            jsonMedia.mJSONMediaInterface = new JSONInterface() {
                                @Override
                                public void startActivityJSON() {
                                    jsonData.getCollections()[finalI].setMediaURL(jsonMedia.getMediaUrl());
                                    mCollectionList.add(jsonData.getCollections()[finalI]);
                                    Log.v("NEWMEDIA", jsonMedia.getMediaUrl());
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        page++;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to read out different pages of JSON object, but it won't work... It always crashes out when I try to do something with the jsonData variable.

Comment: The possible cause of this issue is jsonData.getCollections().length where jsonData is getting initialized but it's collection is still null. So can you have a look at JSON class and also the response because it might be possible that the collection variable inside JSON class is not getting initialised incase of null response/ empty response from API.

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to access the jsonData object, test if it is null first.  If not null then continue.

```
if (jsonData != null) {
   // Array accessing code here
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that call to increment page is still being called even for a null? Might be worth searching/asking for that as a separate question

Comment: What do you mean by that? I think the problem is that it is too slow... it won't load in time so it times out.